# Painting-look-alike filter

Tags: photoshop

Does anybody know where I can find a free filter that would make a picture look like a painting?

I have tried to play around with some of the build-in filters but none of them really made it look like a painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a single filter, but a working tutorial - at least for me: http://www.worth1000.com/tutorial.asp?sid=161032&page=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this question would be more suitable for superuser.com

Painting is much more than that. What kind of painting ? Are you looking for an oil paint look ? Something close pointillism, impressionism, abstract painting, modernism, suprematism ? etc...do you want to make you picture look like a cheap copy of Van Gogh's style ?

If you're looking for **free** why not use GIMP ? There is an awesome set of brushes and other tools that make Gimp comparable to Corel Painter called [Gimp Paint Studio](http://code.google.com/p/gps-gimp-paint-studio/).
Have a look on Google Code and check the wiki/video/etc. [Ramón Miranda](http://ramonmirandavisualart.blogspot.com/) makes some amazing things with it.